# How many different perfect matchings are there in this graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider this graph:

[image]

From the definition, a perfect matching of a graph with $2n$ vertices is a subgraph consisting of $n$ disjoint edges.

The problems is I started counting them one by one and came across too many of them, thus doubted what I was doing. How do you count them? Any theorems? How many are there?

Comment: The answer depends a lot on which graph you have.

Comment: @vadim123 What about this graph with 6 edges and 9 vertices shown above?

Comment: @vadim123, can you elaborate a little more about how?

Comment: Here's an example of how one of such graphs' perfect matchings is counted: [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectMatching.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see 5 subgraphs:
{3 vertical edges},
{nw horizontal, se horizontal, sw-ne diagonal},
{ne horizontal, sw horizontal, nw-se diagonal},
{w vertical, ne horizontal, se horizontal},
{e vertical, nw horizontal, sw horizontal}

Comment: I should have cared more about the word **disjoint**.